# Umbraco 7 - moving site getting a Microsoft.IdentityModel Error when trying to login

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I've developed a site using the Umbraco 7 CMS system, all works great and I've been able to copy and deploy this to numerous other machines and severs without any issues.

However now that we have tried deploying this to the live server, we are unable to login to the backend Umbraco section. The error is as follows:

**Received an error from the server
Server call failed for getting current user
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.
Exception Details: 
 System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.**

The only different here is that the live server is administered by a Plesk control panel. So the actual site within IIS were created using this. However we have full Remote Desktop access and have set all the required "full control" permissions. And have checked that we have the correct .NET versions installed. But with no luck.

Has anyone experienced this or have a fix, I've searched Google and can't find anything that works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run into this myself, but it sounds like the server where you are trying to run your live site does not have the Windows Identity Foundation installed. I'd try installing that on your production server. Alternatively, you could find Microsoft.IdentityModel.dll reference in your solution right click it, open its properties and set Copy Local to true. That will cause the referenced dll to actually be dumped into the bin on compile. If you then deploy those dlls from the bin, your live site should be able to find them. You might have to go through that a couple of times until you find all of the Windows Identity Foundation dlls you need to get to.

It sounds like WIF has been integrated into the .NET 4.5 framework. It is depreciated and you shouldn't use it unless you are developing with .NET 3.5 or 4. I wouldn't expect you to be having this problem on .NET 4.5. What version of .NET framework are you using?

See [What is Windows Identity Foundation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748475.aspx) for more info on WIF

Was any of that helpful?

Comment: The Umbraco instance is a compiled version downloadable via the Umbraco websites, so we do not compile this ourselves.

Comment: I've reflected the DLLs in the Bin directory and they targeting .Net 4. I've checked hat we have the correct versions of .Net and WIF installed. They seems to be there